# Need a solution to start a program at desirable time and close it at desirable time everyday automatically

Tags: windows

I need a solution on windows 7/10 to start a program at desirable time and close it at desirable time everyday automatically.
I'm running a program 24/7 and i need it to close at 00:00am and open it again at 00:01am
It's not very convenient to do it manually so i'm looking for solution. Maybe a .bat file or something i don't know.
I have no experience in coding whatsoever so i'm asking you guys for help.

Comment: No need to code for this. The Microsoft Windows operating system is a very mature system that has a very large set of tools included. The Task Scheduler is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler and define two jobs for start and stop your program at specific time everyday.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at Task Scheduler